# How to get a list of all user groups in Modx Revolution

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

Trying to get a list of group names from modx revolution, digging through the API and docs, but not having much luck finding a function that does this.

How can I get a list of groups [names & ids] in a snippet from a modx revolution instance>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$where = array();
$userGroups = $modx->getCollection('modUserGroup', $where);
foreach ($userGroups as $userGroup) {
    print $userGroup->get('name');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without the loop.

```
<?php
$q = $modx->newQuery('modUserGroup'); 
$q->select(['name']);
$q->prepare();
$q->stmt->execute();
$userGroups = $q->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
print_r($userGroups);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
//Group IDs array
print_r($modx->user->getUserGroups());
//Group Names array
print_r($modx->user->getUserGroupNames());
```